# Having problems reading more than one piece of data in a pickle file

Tags: python, pickle

Here's my code:

```
import sqlite3
import pickle

connection = sqlite3.connect("D:\\Programming\\TradingInvestment\\Datasets\\Binance_Trades_Data.db")
cur = connection.cursor()

asset_list = ["BTC", "ETH", "AAVE", "YFI", "COMP"]

for asset in asset_list:
    table = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM " + asset + "USDT_TXS ORDER BY time")
    for i in table:
        data = cur.fetchone()
        if int(str(data[4])[:-3]) > 1608812669:
            with open(asset + ".pickle", "ab") as file:
                datapoint = (int(str(data[4])[:-3]), data[1])
                pickle.dump(datapoint, file)
```

I then try to use this to read all the datapoints in one of the files:

```
import pickle

file_read =  pickle.load(open("BTC.pickle", "rb"))

for i in file_read:
    print(i)
```

But all I get is the first datapoint... I'm probably missing something simple but can't figure it out

Comment: Without proper data and output to support it with, it's hard to answer such questions.

Comment: If you dump multiple times, you must load multiple times to get all the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead of dumping every datapoint by itself, create a list of datapoints and dump the list:

```py
import sqlite3
import pickle

connection = sqlite3.connect("D:\\Programming\\TradingInvestment\\Datasets\\Binance_Trades_Data.db")
cur = connection.cursor()

asset_list = ["BTC", "ETH", "AAVE", "YFI", "COMP"]

for asset in asset_list:
    table = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM " + asset + "USDT_TXS ORDER BY time")
    datapoints = []
    for i in table:
        data = cur.fetchone()
        if int(str(data[4])[:-3]) > 1608812669:
            datapoint = (int(str(data[4])[:-3]), data[1])
            datapoints.append(datapoint)
    with open(asset + ".pickle", "ab") as file:
        pickle.dump(datapoints, file)
```

And then, when reading, you can use the same code that you're using now but it's not handling the file correctly (it's never closed), instead use this:

```py
import pickle

with open("BTC.pickle", "rb") as f:
    file_read =  pickle.load(f)

for i in file_read:
    print(i)
```

**Edit:** moved the with statement. -Thanks @Steve.

Comment: @zixuan When I started writing my answer the other answer didn't exist. I did not "steal" Steve's solution and implemented it, I thought of this solution myself.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do here, but the code won't work the way you have it.  Your write to `pickle.dump` will fail because `file` will not be pointing to an open file at that point.  You're currently opening each output file a bunch of times, but then not doing anything with it each time.  Move the opening of the output file just before your call to `pickle.dump` and I think this code should work.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for noticing the code was wrong, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match up `pickle.load()` calls with `pickle.dump()` calls 1 for 1.  Here, you're making multiple calls to `pickle.dump()` to write your pickle file, but the you're expecting a single call to `pickle.load()` to read all of your pickled objects at once.  Put your call to `pickle.load()` inside your `for` loop, and you should have better results.

Another thing you can do is put all of your `datapoint` objects in a list and then pickle that list with a single call to `pickle.dump()`.  Then what you're trying to do when you load your serialized objects should work.

It seems strange to me that you open each output file multiple times.  Since you're opening for appending, I guess it should work, but why not open the output file just once outside of the inner loop?  And again, once you've made that change, you're better off building up a single list for each "asset", and then making a single call to `pickle.dump` to serialize that list to file.